# how to proxy specific repo in apt

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, proxy

I recently switched to Ubuntu 15.10.

I need to use a proxy to connect to external internet.And on my local internet there's a repo that doesn't require proxy to connect.

So I wrote something like this in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy

```
Acquire::http::Proxy::google.com "http://XXX:8087";
Acquire::http::Proxy::spotify.com "http://XXX:8087";
```

Unfortunately,this doesn't work, apt-get update says failed to connect google spotify.
I also tried change it to this.

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://XXX:8087";
```

I can connect to google and spotify now, but I can't connect to my local repo.
  Isn't there a better workaround?

Comment: Are you connecting to `google.com` or `dl.google.com` or `www.google.com`, or some other subdomain of `google.com` altogether?

Comment: yes, it's dl.google.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a file: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99proxy` and in this file insert the following:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy {
    your.local.repository DIRECT;
};
```

This tells apt to use a direct connection (so not via proxy) to access your local repository.

Change `your.local.repository` to the correct location of your local repository.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's my fault all alone,changing 'Acquire::http::Proxy::google.com "http://XXX:8087";' to'Acquire::http::Proxy::dl.google.com "http://XXX:8087";' worked